# asp.net website add to Trusted site problem?

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net application which is running great but I installed same application on new server when I run my application browser shows “You are not authorized to view this Page”. When I add  my application link in trusted site it work properly without any error message.
 I am scared why my application behaves differently for that particular server. 
Please suggest possible solution to avoid above mentioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing that springs to mind is that you are on a network with a domain account. The site you are accessing, for one reason or another, is not being picked up as local intranet and so, by default, your browser is not forwarding your domain credentials to the remote site. 
Once you add it to the trusted sites, it will.

Can you have a look at the bottom right of your browser (assuming IE here) and tell me what "zone" it says (local intranet, internet, etc) when accessing the remote server. If it doesn't say "Local Intranet" it may be the cause.

Are you accessing this server by IP address? This will always fail to resolve as "Local Intranet".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your reply. When we try to access application by using IP Address 
a logon dialog box is presented to enter credentials and browser's status bar shows "Local Intranet" zone.

In our web.config file we have given form authentication as follows

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="OurApplication" loginUrl="login.aspx"/>
</authentication>

    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
        <!-- Allow all users -->
</authorization>
```

In the IIS authentication section under directory security tab following setting is applied.

Enable Anonymous Access is true
Integrated Windows Authentication is true.

With the above settings same application is working fine on DR and UAT Servers but not on the production server.

Please tell me the way to avoid the logon dialog box.

Best Regards,

Neil